# Saving value from page 1 to page 2 - uiWebView

Tags: javascript, html, ios, uiwebview

Looking for a way to pass my 2 values from box 1 and 2 on page 1 to value box 1 and 2 on page 2 so i want to move the value between pages.

Hard part i'm using it in a offline Ios uiWebView and i cant get it to work, with local value storage or something similar.

I'm working inside a html page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

It looks like you can use localstorage in the uiwebview the same way as you can in other full browsers (Which is what Joran ended up finding to work).

But you could also use the following if you want access to the variables in objective-c.

**ORIGINAL:**

Try using an [Objective-c Javascript Bridge (Apple Docs)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/ObjCFromJavaScript.html). It allows you to essentially pass values back and forth between your objective-c code and the javascript page (Just like it sounds haha).

So you could store the values in an objective c NSMutableDictionary and pass them on to the next page when it changes.

Comment: Hi @SnoApps Thank will look into it is there no simpler way like saving value temporary in js

Comment: I can't seem to find anywhere where there's an easier way (except, some people say you can use localStorage but it seems iffy). But it doesn't have to be complex. Just use something as simple as this `NSString *formVal = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"return document.getElementById('myInput').value;"];`

Answer (score 0):

My problem was simply solved by using LocalStorage in javascript to save the value this surprisingly worked.

Thanks for the help @SnoApps